# What is the best resource to research the current state of asset classes for mutual funds?

Tags: stocks, bonds, websites, asset-allocation, markets

I have a fairly simple asset allocation as follows:

- 50% Large Cap stocks
- 15% Small Cap Stocks
- 5% REIT
- 10% International Stocks
- 20% Bonds

What is the best web site to track how each one of these asset classes is **currently** doing? For example, I found

1. [CNNMoney article saying that small caps are overvalued](http://money.cnn.com/2010/08/04/pf/funds/small_cap_stocks.moneymag/index.htm)
2. [Bloomberg article saying that large caps are on the verge of growth](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2011-02-24/richest-investors-come-back-to-big-cap-stocks-in-hunt-for-yield.html)

I know that every publication has it's own bias and can only be trusted so far. But I would like a quick place to go to for a broad view of each major asset class.

Comment: Have you tried MorningStar's Portfolio?

Comment: Just curious..you have nothing in liquid cash? Like a savings account?

Answer (score 3):

I'd just use your favorite portfolio manager and choose a representative index for each of your asset classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think my question was misinterpreted. What I was wondering is what everyone's favorite web site for commentary and opinion on each asset class like the 2 articles I referenced above. Not a tool to track my specific portfolio.

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://assetbuilder.com/our_portfolios/portfolio_list.aspx) has a good list of model portfolios that you can look at to compare your asset allocation against what they are using.
Another [link to a article](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748704881304576094281304816382.html?KEYWORDS=SHEFALI+ANAND) about diversification in WSJ